# Dynamically check the input as the user types

Tags: c++, validation

In a C++ program I want to check the user input as he types. I want to get a string from the user, but I need to make sure the user enters not more than 25 words in the string. The input must automatically stop on the 25th word and the program must go ahead. Is there any function in C++ that can do this purpose. `getch()` can get a single character, but that is not what I want.

Comment: Simple answer is "no". If you want to strictly check what someone types, you have to deal with character by character, and build the string yourself. Is "coffee-maker" one word or two, by the way? ;)

Comment: coffee-maker considered as a word.. :)
So if it is character by character, can i still get a string? how?

Comment: You will need to read a character at a time, and build the string - you probably also need to deal with backspace, delete and such. Alternatively, you can "post-check" -read the input and check if it's got more than 25 words.